# Despite updating value , old value is displayed on react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here in this React component I am declaring a simple variable called `companyData` and assigned default value as `"james"`. And then updated the value of `companyData` with a new value that I received from axios request.

Though in log, I do see updated value, but within return space (JSX), it gives only old delcared value `"james"` on loading component.

How can I make sure only the latest value get displayed?

```js
function Home(props) {
  var companyData = "james";
  axios
    .post(
      "https://…..",
      {
        withCredentials: true,

        headers: {
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
          Pragma: "no-cache",
          Expires: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        auth: {
          username: "",
          password: "",
        },
        data: {
          action: "asdf",
        },
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      companyData = response.data;
      console.log(companyData); // it returs updated data received from axios post
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

    return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {companyData} // here I still received old value james as output 
      <Text>
    <View>    
   ) 
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your variable with a state ([useState](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) hook) because when `Home` gets called/recalled, regular variables are reinitilized since `Home` is a function after all.

Now to fetch data when the component mounts we usually use [useEffect](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) for that, and with an empty [dependency array](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#specifying-reactive-dependencies) `[]`, we make the effect runs only once, after the component first render.

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// ...

function Home(props) {
  const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState("james");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.post(
      'https://...',
      {
        // ...
      }
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      setCompanyData(response.data);
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }, []); // Empty dependency array 

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>
        {companyData}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

What will happen is that during the first render "james" is displayed since JSX is returned before `useEffect` runs, but you will not notice it because just after that `useEffect` will run and updates the state so the component rerenders and now the new value assigned to `companyData` is displayed during this new render.

---

**Good to know:** 
If you want to use a variable that you don't want to lose its value when the component rerenders you can make use of [useRef](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef)

Answer (score 0):

In react we usually use "useState" to make variables.
useState returns two values, the variable and a function that is used to change the variable. It writes like this :

```
import { useState } from "react";
... // when declaring the function you use 
const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState("james")
```

here the initial variable is "james"
the change it you have to use the function "setCompanyData" like so :

```
setCompanyData("new data")
```

so you final code should look something like this :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"; // At the top of the file
....
function Home(props) {
const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState("james");
useEffect(() => {
axios
.post(
  "https://…..",
  {
    withCredentials: true,

headers: {
      "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
      Pragma: "no-cache",
      Expires: 0,
    },
  },
  {
    auth: {
      username: "",
      password: "",
    },
    data: {
      action: "asdf",
    },
  }
)
.then(function (response) {
  setCompanyData(response.data)
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});}, [] ) // important brackets !!!

return (
<View>
  <Text>
    {companyData} // here you will receive new value as output 
  <Text>
<View>    
) 
}

export default Home;
```